# Duplicate values with comma are added after update operation in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working with a Nested Grid view with add, update, and delete functionality. The add and delete operations are working successfully. There is an issue while updating the inner grid's particular entry, it updates the value with the previous value by comma separated. I don't know why this is happening.

While updating the outer grid values, it updates fine without duplicate values.

My code for my nested gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdViewMaster" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    DataKeyNames="MasterID" CssClass="dataTable" ShowFooter="true"
    OnRowCommand="grdViewMaster_RowCommand" OnRowEditing="grdViewMaster_RowEditing" 
    OnRowUpdating="grdViewMaster_RowUpdating"
    OnRowDeleting="grdViewMaster_RowDeleting" 
    OnRowCancelingEdit="grdViewMaster_RowCancelingEdit" 
    OnRowDataBound="grdViewMaster_OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Options" ItemStyle-CssClass="mastertabletd" HeaderStyle-CssClass="mastertabletd" FooterStyle-CssClass="mastertabletd">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdateMaster" CommandName="Update" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/1-update.png" ToolTip="Update" Height="15px" Width="15px" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancelMaster" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/images/1-Cancel.png" ToolTip="Cancel" Height="15px" Width="15px" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEditMaster" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/1-edit.png" ToolTip="Edit" Height="15px" Width="15px" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDeleteMaster" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" runat="server" ToolTip="Delete" Height="15px" Width="15px" />
                <a href="javascript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("MasterID")%>')">
                    <img id='imgdiv<%# Eval("MasterID")%>' alt="Details" src="images/plus.png" />
                </a>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnAddMaster" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/1-add.png" CommandName="AddNewMaster" Width="15px" Height="15px" ToolTip="Add new User" ValidationGroup="validaiton" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Style #" ItemStyle-CssClass="mastertabletd" HeaderStyle-CssClass="mastertabletd" FooterStyle-CssClass="mastertabletd">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditStyleID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("StyleID") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtStyleID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StyleID") %>' />                  
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtftrStyleID" runat="server" CssClass="width90per" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="0" HeaderStyle-Width="0" 
            FooterStyle-Width="0" ItemStyle-CssClass="mastertabletd" 
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="mastertabletd" FooterStyle-CssClass="mastertabletd">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id='div<%# Eval("MasterID")%>' style="display: none;" class="dataTables_wrapper">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvExcelData" DataKeyNames="ID" runat="server" 
                        GridLines="Horizontal" ShowFooter="true" CssClass="dataTable" 
                        BorderStyle="None" EmptyDataText="No Data Found" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        OnRowCommand="gvExcelData_RowCommand" 
                        OnRowEditing="gvExcelData_RowEditing" 
                        OnRowUpdating="gvExcelData_RowUpdating" 
                        OnRowDeleting="gvExcelData_RowDeleting" 
                        OnRowCancelingEdit="gvExcelData_RowCancelingEdit">
                        <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="form-horizontal fill-up validatable width100per" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Options">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/1-update.png" ToolTip="Update" Height="15px" Width="15px" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/images/1-Cancel.png" ToolTip="Cancel" Height="15px" Width="15px" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/1-edit.png" ToolTip="Edit" Height="15px" Width="15px" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" CommandName="Delete" Text="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" ToolTip="Delete" Height="15px" Width="15px" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnAdd" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/1-add.png" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MasterID") %>' OnClientClick="return validateInputField(this);" CommandName="AddNew" Width="15px" Height="15px" ToolTip="Add new User" ValidationGroup="validaiton" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField> 
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor #">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtVendorID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("VendorID") %>' />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div style="display: none">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblMasterID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MasterID") %>' />
                                    </div>
                                    <%#Eval("VendorID") %>                                                                               
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtftrVendorID" CssClass="txtftrVendorID" runat="server" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <PagerStyle CssClass="custom-pagination" />
                        <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" FirstPageText="Prev" LastPageText="Next" PageButtonCount="5" Position="Bottom" />
                        <FooterStyle CssClass="custom-footer" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is my cs files code.

```
string gvUniqueID = String.Empty;    
int gvEditIndex = -1;
protected void grdViewMaster_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNewMaster"))
        {
            if (isChildAdded)
                return;
            TextBox txtStyleID = (TextBox)grdViewMaster.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrStyleID");
            string StyleID = txtStyleID.Text;
            if (StyleID != string.Empty)
            {
                InsertMasterRecord(StyleID); /* My Database function which Insert values to database */;
                BindMasterGrid();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Common.LogError(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
protected void grdViewMaster_RowEditing(Object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    grdViewMaster.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindMasterGrid();
}

// in that master row update, this works fine. no duplicate data here.
protected void grdViewMaster_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int recordId = Convert.ToInt32(grdViewMaster.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

        TextBox txtStyleID = (TextBox)grdViewMaster.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditStyleID");
        string StyleID = txtStyleID.Text;
        if (StyleID != string.Empty)
        {
            UpdateMasterRecord(StyleID, recordId);  /* My Database function which updates this values */;
            grdViewMaster.EditIndex = -1;
            BindMasterGrid();                
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

protected void grdViewMaster_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    // my delete logic here which works fine.
}

protected void grdViewMaster_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    grdViewMaster.EditIndex = -1;
    BindMasterGrid();
}

protected void grdViewMaster_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row;
    string strSort = string.Empty;
    if (row.DataItem == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv = (GridView)row.FindControl("gvExcelData"); // for binding the inner grid datas.

    if (gv.UniqueID == gvUniqueID)
    {
        gv.PageIndex = gvNewPageIndex;
        gv.EditIndex = gvEditIndex;           
    }
    gv.DataSource = /* My Database function which returns DataTable*/;
    gv.DataBind();

}
protected void gvExcelData_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GridView gvExcelData = (GridView)sender;
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
        {
            Label lblMasterID = (Label)gvExcelData.NamingContainer.FindControl("lblMasterID");
            int masterID = Convert.ToInt32(lblMasterID.Text);
            TextBox txtVendorID = (TextBox)gvExcelData.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrVendorID");
            string vendorID = txtVendorID.Text;
            if (masterID != 0)
            {
                insertToDatabase(masterID,vendorID); // my inserted database logic here..
                BindMasterGrid();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
protected void gvExcelData_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gvTemp = (GridView)sender;
    gvUniqueID = gvTemp.UniqueID;
    gvEditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;       
    BindMasterGrid();
}

// here i got the duplicate values by comma separated while updating the values.
protected void gvExcelData_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GridView gvExcelData = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow gr = gvExcelData.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        int recordId = Convert.ToInt32(gvExcelData.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        TextBox txtVendorID = (TextBox)gr.FindControl("txtVendorID");
        string vendorID = txtVendorID.Text;
        UpdateToDatabase(recordId,VendorID); // my method for updating the database values.
        gvExcelData.EditIndex = -1;
        BindMasterGrid();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
protected void gvExcelData_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    // my delete methods for deleting the values which works superb.
}
protected void gvExcelData_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gvExcelData = (GridView)sender;
    gvExcelData.EditIndex = -1;
    BindMasterGrid();
}
```

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: -1 for terrible formatting...

Comment: Improved formatting. now, please

Answer (score 0):

Since you said your insert works just fine, your problem may have to do with the vendor ID you are passing to your update method.

Insert:

```
string vendorID = txtVendorID.Text;
insertToDatabase(masterID,vendorID);
```

Update:

```
string vendorID = txtVendorID.Text;
UpdateToDatabase(recordId,VendorID);
```